# Subsetting data by date variables (Stata)

Tags: subset, stata

I would like to check the number of workers on a given week or month. The month variable in the data browser looks like "Jan2018", while the week variable like "06jan2018".

To count the number of workers in a given week, I ran the code below:

```
preserve
    keep if week==06jan2018
    distinct union_workers
restore
```

And I got the following error "06jan2018 invalid name".

The week and month variables look as follows:

```
*Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float week int month
21211 696
21211 696
21211 696
21204 696
21211 696
21190 696
21204 696
21190 696
21190 696
21190 696
21211 696
21204 696
21211 696
21204 696
end

format %td week
format %tmMonYY month
```

```
describe month week

              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
month           int     %tmMonYY              
week            float   %td
```

What is the best method to count the number of workers and subset the data by a given date, given the format of the week and month variables listed above?

Comment: `distinct` is community-contributed from the _Stata Journal_, as you are asked to explain (Stata tag wiki).

Comment: If the problem is precisely as stated, finding the number of distinct workers on a particular data, well and good. If you want to count repeatedly, see https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0042 for alternatives.

Comment: ... a particular date ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get an error is that in `week==06jan2018` you test for all values where the variable `week` is similar to variable `06jan2018`. I understand that that is not what you mean to do but that is what you are telling your code to do. I understand that you do not have a variable called `06jan2018` and you would not be able to as in Stata you cannot have a variable name that starts on a digit.

If your variable `week` would have been a string variable (text variable) then you could have done `week=="06jan2018"` to compare `week` to the string `06jan2018`. However, your variables are numeric with display formats. This is the most efficient way to work with dates in Stata but you need to understand that you can only do conditional operations with the underlying value and not the dispayed format. The date Jan 6, 2018 corresponds to `21190` in Stata. See your own `dataex` example and [read the documentation for how to work with dates in Stata](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/u24.pdf).

So you could do:

```
preserve
    keep if week==21190
    distinct union_workers
restore
```

But whether that is the best practice depends on how you intend to use this count. Will you just transfer it to a paper/Word doc, or will you merge it back into the worker dataset?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use it for a Word doc. However, is there a way to see that 21190 is equivalent to week=="06jan2018"?
I understand its shown in the dataex, but how can I interpret these numbers into the dates in mind?

Comment: `display %td 21990` and `display daily("6jan2018", "DMY")` are ways to see the conversion. This follows from the documentation suggested to you by @TheIceBear.

Comment: Should be `21190`, it seems.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the variable `week` is stored as a *float*, not a string. 06jan2018 is only the formatted display of the underlying date value in your variable, similar to labeled integers.

To refer to the observations in this week, you need to use the float value, which is 21190 for the week of 06jan2018. So the following code should work:

```
preserve

    keep if week == 21190 
    distinct union_workers

restore
```